# The "Rename" dialog box in Visual Studio 2015 is all wrong

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I right-click on a variable and select "rename" in VS2015, I get a dialog box that has NO "new name" option. It only show me 3 check boxes "Include Comments", "Include string" and "preview changes". Nowhere is there a text box for me to enter the new name. If I select "ABC", it will attempt to rename "ABC" to "ABC".
Why isn't mine looking like the one I see in the tutorials that has "New Name" "Symbol" type, and "Search Scope" options?

Comment: Just start typing the new name after selecting 'rename' in the menu (or Ctrl R R)

Comment: I just spent 2 hours looking through videos and posts on refactoring in Visual Studio and did not see this. I just finished watching a YouTube on refactoring in Visual Studio 2015 ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMpK5O7Zbx8 ) which shows that I should be getting the dialog box that I described in my question. This may be a trivial question to many of you. But it was wasn't to me. These new features are not very intuitive if you haven't been shown them.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is "highlighted" in the code editor and act as a text box.